# How to use Doxygen's "Documentation at other places" feature with a specialized template class?

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

I'm facing a very unimportant problem with Doxygen. But as I was unable to find an answer over the Internet and as I am very curious, I come here to ask you to share your knowledge.

When I'm working on a class, I used to define small parts on documentation at their standard places, but I also used to define big documentation parts like code examples or  verbatim at the bottom of the header file instead of defining them on top of each classes.
Those I need to use the "Documentation at other places" feature of Doxygen.

Here is a working example:

```
/** This is my class description */
class MyClass
    {
    ...
};


/*! @class MyClass
@code
    ...some code example
@endcode */
```

And that usually does work very well.

But today I'm trying to use the same method with a specialized template class, and I'm unable to make it go at the correct place in the documentation.

Here is a non working example:

```
/** This is my class description */
template < class Tr, class... Args >
class MyClass<Tr(Args...)> : public MyBaseClass {
    ...
};


/*! @class MyClass<Tr(Args...)>
@code
    ...some code example
@endcode */
```

I searched the documentation, the Doxyfile and over Internet but I'm still unable to tell if I don't do it as it should be done, or if this is a "bug" or non usual case.

Thank you for your enlightenment.

---

Edit : I did some more tests with a simplest template class (without specialization) and that does not work either.

```
/** This is my class description */
template < class Tr >
class MyClass
{
    ...
};


/*! @class MyClass // @class MyClass< Tr > // @class template < Tr > MyClass
@code
    ...some code example
@endcode */
```

I tried specifying the template after or before the class name, with or without the "template" keyword, and using the class name only, but it doesn't seems to work in any way.

---

Edit 2: It does works with simple template classes. The previous edit test was not working because I had defined the class into a namespace without specifying the namespace in the Doxygen comment : @class namespace::MyClass

But it still doesn't work with specialized template classes, and I am still unable to redirect a comment bloc to a specialized template class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't put the template parameter there. Do something like that:

```
/** This is my class description */
template < class Tr, class... Args >
class MyClass<Tr(Args...)> : public MyBaseClass {
    ...
};

/*! @class MyClass
@code 
    ...some code example
@endcode */
```

I'm not sure if it works (don't have doxygen installed here), but I think it should.

Comment: Well it does not; I defined it just like that at first, as I thought it should work as with other classes. I just did some test and it doesn't work even with a simple template class (not specialized).

Comment: It finally does works with simple template class (I was forgetting the namespace into the Doxygen class tag), but still does not work with specialized through.